# QT OpenGL Memory Leak

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, memory-leaks

My application contains a QTimer, as the main clock, and a GLCanvas object. The timer is calling the canvas updateGL function and the updateGL then calls the paintGL.

I noticed a big memory leak of approximately 100kb/s which exists even if paintGL is completely empty and nothing is being rendered. If I stop the updateGL call, the memory leak disappears.

Although all my code is commented out and the leak persists. Is there some sort of clearing I need to do or did I make a mistake? Any help would be appreciated.

```
    void GLCanvas::initializeGL() {
        glClearColor(21.0f/256.0f,21.0f/256.0f, 21.0f/256.0f, 1);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    }

    void GLCanvas::resizeGL(int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45, (float)width/(float)height, 1, 1000);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }



    void GLCanvas::paintGL() {
        // Nothing
    }
```

Comment: How are you detecting this memory leak?

Comment: The application slows down and eventually crashes. Also, looked at the task manager.

Comment: How did you determine that the memory leak occurs in the provided code?

Comment: When paintGL does not get called (by updateGL) there is no leak. The above code is but a snippet.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a larger code snippet since it's hard to imagine the structure of your GLCanvas class. If possible, it should contain your class's constructor and destructor.

Comment: I have found the problem but not solved it. My software is using several instances of the GLCanvas object and updating them separately. Memory starts increasing the second two or more updateGL functions are being called.

Comment: @user2487807 Are you making any OpenGL calls outside of the methods you listed above?  If so, it may that your problem is that you're not calling makeCurrent() on the GLCanvas object before executing the OpenGL calls.  Since the OpenGL calls are global (i.e. they don't take a GLCanvas argument to tell OpenGL which canvas to operate on) they are probably sometimes operating on the 'wrong' GLCanvas object, which causes state changes that GLCanvas doesn't expect.  (In paintGL(), resizeGL(), and initializeGL() makeCurrent() isn't necessary as GLCanvas calls it for you, but elsewhere, it is)

Answer (score 0):

How often do your timer call update()?

What is the timer for? Maybe you can work your way out of the Qtimer for such important task.